# Pandas - Populando múltiplas planilhas a partir de uma

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Tenho um relatório com informações gerais e preciso gerar um reporte específico para cada escritório (eles são especificados pelo nome mesmo).

No caso, já criei planilhas separadas em uma pasta específica, criei as abas a serem preenchidas, porém não consegui ter o eureka: **Como poderia fazer a separação na base geral e levar os dados para a planilha correspondente?**

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pathlib import Path

planilha_geral  = pd.read_excel(r"endereço planilha")
semana_apuracao = input("Insira a data da semana de apuração")

#criando pasta para inserir planilhas
tableau = Path.cwd() / 'TABLEAU'.format(semana_apuracao)
tableau.mkdir(parents = True,exist_ok = True)

#criando arquivo separado para cada escr
for i,escritorio in enumerate(planilha_geral['Escritorio'].unique()):
    wrkbk = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wrkbk.create_sheet('LIMINAR')
    sheet = wrkbk.create_sheet('APREENSÃO')
    sheet = wrkbk.create_sheet('LEV. PET.')
    sheet = wrkbk.create_sheet('PURGA')
    sheet = wrkbk.create_sheet('FULL DATA')
    wrkbk.save(tableau / f'{escritorio}.xlsx')

#percorrendo pasta com arquivos criados acima
for arquivo in tableau.iterdir():
    print(arquivo.name)
```

Agradeço!

Comment: Só para entender, você tem uma base de dados e quer transformar cada coluna em um sheet com seu respectivo dados?

Comment: Oi @KaiqueNakao!  Na vdd é qse isso: 
Tenho a base de dados geral e preciso "quebrá-la" em relatórios separados para cada um dos escritórios.  

Pra tentar me fazer mais clara, manualmente seria: copiar dados de escritório 1 da primeira aba > colar na planilha do escritorio 1 na primeira aba > copiar dados de escritorio 1 da segunda aba > colar na planilha do escritorio 1 na segunda aba  e assim sucessivamente :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei o seu código e verifiquei que as planilhas não recebem os valores correspondentes das linhas. Pelo que eu entendi no seu código está fazendo um `for` com os valores únicos da coluna `Escritório` utilizando o `planilha_geral['Escritorio'].unique()`, e com isso cria um planilhas diferente com os valores da coluna `Escritório`. Mas não sei o certo se é para separar a base geral em sheet ou em planilhas diferentes, com isso vou  fazer as duas opções.

### Separando a base de dados em diferentes planilhas

Digamos que temos esse seguinte excel (em anexo), e queremos transformar as linhas da coluna Escritório em diferentes planilhas com seu valor respectivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Importante: seus dados tem que estar nesse formato, seguindo esses índices, caso os seus dados encontram-se em um index diferente, você tem que passar no parâmetro do `read_csv` o [skip_rows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Código

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Informando o caminho que se encontra o excel com a base de dados
path = r"C:\\Users\\Kaique Nakao\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\pandas\\escritorios.xlsx"

# Lendo a base de dados, onde passo a minha path 
# e o SHEET NAME que a minha base de dados se encontra
dados = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Exibindo a base de dados
dados.head()
```

output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Beleza agora tendo lido a base de dados, agora basta rodar o `for` percorrendo os valores únicos da coluna `Escritório` e criando as planilhas. (Bem parecido com o processo do seu código)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists="replace")

# Percorro o for através dos valores únicos do escritorio e faço 
# uma condição para buscar as linhas correspondente e crio a planilha
for i, escritorio in enumerate(np.unique(dados['Escritorio'])):
    dados[dados['Escritorio'] == escritorio].to_excel(f'{escritorio}.xlsx', sheet_name=escritorio, index=False)
    
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

**Resultado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

###### Código Completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Informando o caminho que se encontra o excel com a base de dados
path = r"C:\\Users\\Kaique Nakao\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\pandas\\escritorios.xlsx"

# Lendo a base de dados, onde passo a minha path 
# e o SHEET NAME que a minha base de dados se encontra
dados = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists="replace")

# Percorro o for através dos valores únicos do escritorio e faço 
# uma condição para buscar as linhas correspondente e crio a planilha
for i, escritorio in enumerate(np.unique(dados['Escritorio'])):
    dados[dados['Escritorio'] == escritorio].to_excel(f'{escritorio}.xlsx', sheet_name=escritorio, index=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

### Separando a base de dados em diferentes sheet

Utilizando o mesmo arquivo `"escritorios.xlsx"`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = r"C:\\Users\\Kaique Nakao\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\pandas\\escritorios.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists="replace")

dados = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Percorro o for e crio  o sheet name no mesmo arquivo que a base de dados e passo os valores da linha
for i, escritorio in enumerate(np.unique(dados['Escritorio'])):
    dados[dados['Escritorio'] == escritorio].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=escritorio, index=False)
    
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

**Resultado** (ambos com os valores correspondentes):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Demais @Kaique Nakao! Ajudou completamente, vou apenas adaptar pro que preciso. Agradeço muito.